# Selenium Jmeter differences on websocket calls

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I am researching the differences between Selenium and JMeter and I stumbled across the following statement about Selenium:

> Even though WebSocket might be encapsulated into a web session and
>   affect the browser, the user/Selenium will not realise it. So, we will
>   use JMeter for testing WebSockets.

which confuses me because even though Selenium can't detect that specific scenario, Selenium still uses a programming language like JAVA, hence you can still use Java to accomplish the same thing JMeter does in this case. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Selenium doesn't use a programming language.  The programming language uses Selenium... you could write your own Selenium library and your own JMeter library if you wanted to.

Comment: @pcalkins okay, how does that answer my question in any way?

Comment: You could write your own code, or you could use JMeter...  but I may not understand the question.  Selenium calls communicate with the webdriver... the webdriver controls and communicates with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're reading however I would recommend stopping referring this source as they don't really realize what they're talking about.

According to [The WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) documentation:

> The WebSocket API is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open a two-way interactive communication session between the **user's browser** and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

[Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) is **browser** automation framework therefore you get this WebSocket API support "for free". If you need to perform some custom use cases you can use [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) to call [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) object functions.

When it comes to [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Therefore JMeter will not trigger any WebSocket-related events unless you use a [plugin and manually open connection, send message, read response](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/), etc.